# How to run a JNLP file with SQLite DB?

Tags: java, sqlite, javafx-2, jnlp, java-web-start

I'm new to JavaFX. I have a JavaFX Application which is generating a jar and a JNLP file. As a DB I'm using SQLite db. The system runs fine when running it on Netbeans IDE but does not get going with built files (jnlp, jar). Problem is the JNLP is unable to find the db location when running with JNLP.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sign your application](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/packaging.htm#BABJGFBH) to give it the permissions it needs to run correctly in jnlp mode.

Answer (score 2):

How is the DB installed?

Presuming the installer can accept an 'installation path', I would tend to:

1. Use an `installer-desc` element to start Java code.
2. That pops a `JFileChooser` to allow the user to create/select an installation directory
3. That it then passes (that path) to the DB installer, and..
4. Persists the path using the `PersistenceService`

When the main GUI starts, it can:

1. Read the DB path from the `PersistenceService`
2. Invoke/start the DB.

For demos. of some of the parts of that, see:

1. The [`PersistenceService`](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#ps).
2. The `installer-desc` that invokes the [`ExtensionInstallerService`](http://pscode.org./jws/api.html#eis).

Answer (score 0):

If you have permissions on the machine you're running on and the user accepted them you should be able to write a new database file to the local system.

Make sure that you check that the database exists and if not create it.  Failing that, what is the exception?